# Ramda - allPass returns true, even if one of the conditions is false

Tags: javascript, typescript, evaluation, ramda.js

I am using Ramda, to clean up my code. I have some complex Checks I need to do. And I decided instead of `&&` and `||` to use the `allPass` and `anyPass` from ramda.

But I have an issue. AllPass, will return `true` even if one of the conditions is false, while a regular && returns false.

The first check is false, and the second true. Yet, this weird thing is happening.

```
// Regulr &&, returns false
  const emptyView =
    R.contains(itemType, [IItemType.ONE, IItemType.TWO]) &&
    R.equals(mode, IViewMode.VIEW);

// Ramda allPass returns true
  const emptyView = R.allPass([
    R.contains(itemType, [IItemType.JSON, IItemType.AVRO]),
    R.equals(mode, IViewMode.VIEW),
  ]);
```

Can someone explain to me why? I tried both variations of Ramda. A plain Array, and also calling the function, with th necessary info, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are u sure that the second `emptyView` isn't just a function and therefore always evaluates to `true`?

Comment: I think of `allPass` as acting like `allPass([f, g, h]) //~-> (x, y) => f(x, y) && g(x, y) && (h(x, y)`.  The number of arguments in the generated function is the largest arity of `f`, `g`, and `h` (ideally they should all be the same)  and of course the number of functions you actually pass to it is up to you.  But it is *not* a replacement for `foo && bar && baz`.  It takes functions and generates a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the first `emptyView` is actually of type boolean,
the second one is just a function (which in javascript always evaluates to true).

I think that the following is what you really need,
a function that can tell you whether the `itemType` and the `mode` are correct.

```js
const IItemType = {
  JSON: 1,
  AVRO: 2
};

const IViewMode = {
 VIEW: 'view',
};

const fn = R.useWith(R.and, [
  R.contains(R.__, [IItemType.JSON, IItemType.AVRO]),
  R.equals(IViewMode.VIEW),
]);

console.log(
  'it should be true =>', 
  fn(1, 'view'),
);

console.log(
  'it should be false =>', 
  fn(1, 'something-but-view'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```